# PHP - exec not working to run java file

Tags: java, php, exec

I have been searching the internet for hours trying to figure this out but it makes no sense.

I am using `exec()` from PHP, and it works for one class file in a directory, but will not execute another one, this is my code:

```
exec("cd '/path/to/directory';java helloWorld 2>&1", $output);
```

that one works just fine, but the next one doesn't work, I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` when I try it:

```
exec("cd '/path/to/same/directory';java otherClass 2>&1", $output);
```

It just makes no sense to me why one file would work but not the other ones in the same directory. I made sure that it could access the whole directory.

Comment: can you post complete exception ? and code written in otherClass ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was that there was a duplicate of `helloWorld.class` in the same folder as my PHP which was the one being run instead of the one in my directory. It wasn't able to execute the `cd` command but could still run the class file in the same directory.

The problem that I can't figure out now is why it is not able to go to the directory.  It says that it is a permission problem, but when I output `exec("whoami")` I get `_www` and the owner of the directory is `_www` and the owner has read, write, and execute permissions.

**EDIT:**

I gave `_www` access to all of the directories above the directory i want access to and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

check the java class's package name, if it has any, try `java packagename.OtherClass`